# Set default browser on multiple remote computers that are not on the domain

Tags: browser, remote, file-association

I am trying to set the default browser on multiple remote computers that are not on the domain. There are more than 200 computers, so it would be very time consuming to do it manually. The remote computers have Windows 7 operating system with outdated updates.

Comment: Do you have any kind of remote management software installed on these computers?

Comment: @gronostaj No I don't. What do have in mind? Some examples...

Comment: Assuming you know which registry entries to set, and that you have admin access to those machines, you could use psexec (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) or Remote Powershell (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands) to do that.

Comment: Or, if you can access the system drive of those computers, copy a batch file that modifies these settings to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`